# How to know who remote triggered the job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I can trigger the Job using POST request using

`curl -u USER:password JENKINSURL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=mytoken123`

But in Jenkins job, I see 
"Started by remote host EXTERNAL IP"

What I am expecting is
"Started by remote host from USER EXTERNAL IP"

I couldn't find any plugins which does it.